# Extra text issue in IE7 only

Tags: html, css, drupal

I am getting extra text `<![endif]-->` in IE7  but on all other browsers does not show.
I searched this code in all files but didn't find it. I am using Drupal-7.

Please check this link [here](http://indivar.bubblespan.com)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't writing those end tags correctly in some areas. Some places you put this:
 `<!--<![endif]-->`

Change that to this:
`<![endif]-->`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an extra `<![endif]-->` here

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://indivar.bubblespan.com/sites/default/files/css/css_SCgABqUC566L7vt9DqHzb_pIQdEOcwHOijyO95sLhUI.orig.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<![endif]-->
```

Although it is difficult to tell with all the conditional comments you are using.

Better to use fewer comments and to combine content within the conditional comments as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to re-install conditional css module which you are using for drupal.